# IPV6 Small Business Implementation - Windows DHCP/DNS, PFSense, IPV6

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp, ipv6, pfsense

I have some confusion about IPV6 on a Small Business Network.  I'm sure one part or the other is covered extensively, but I can't seem to find answers.

1. (Background info) I have a home network that uses PFSense/Comcast.  PFSense is the DHCP/DNS server and IPV6 RA is set to unmanaged.  IPV6 works fine there.
2. I have a work setup consisting of:
   a.  Comcast Business Internet
   b.  PFSense Firewall/Router
   c.  Windows 2012R2 AD/DNS/DHCP server.
3. IPV6 Windows DHCP/DHCPv6 is enabled at work.
   a. Windows DHCPv6 is running and is handing out addresses in the FDC2: range.
   b.  Computers can use the IPV6 addresses handed to them to "talk" to each other just fine.
   c.  Of course, All IPV4 functions/NAT are working fine.  This is a well established network.
4. I enabled IPV6 on the PFSense/Firewall, used the config tutorials and PFSense has WAN and LAN IPV6 addresses in the 2603:  range
   PFSense can ping IPV6 sites from its own interface.

I have no idea where to go from here to get those 2603 addresses to the local computers so that they can talk to ipv6 sites on the internet.  Or, conversely.. if I should.

Do I use the 2603: prefix in Windows DHCP instead of FDC2 ?  To me this does not sound correct but .. as I said; I am somewhat lost from here.  I am assuming for a machine to talk to a IPV6 WAN, it needs a global address, similar to what it looks like at my house.

Comment: You need a router with DHCPv6 prefix delegation, and pfSense doesn't (yet) have this functionality.

Comment: "By default, the DHCPv6 server is enabled on the LAN interface and set to use a prefix obtained by tracking WAN's DHCPv6 delegation"

Comment: At home, this works with PFSense.  At work, I don't want PFSense to delegate anything(just a firewall; nothing else). I am of the belief that Windows DHCPv6 needs to do this.  So, yes I agree that PFSense not providing but passing at home (Which is fine).  I just wanted to know how this would work in a Windows environment.  Either that or I am making this way too hard...or really misunderstanding something.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you need to have Windows doing DHCPv6. If pfSense finally supports this, then go for it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but work is work.  We use Windows integrated AD with DHCP and DNS.  I understand that I could throw away the Windows servers and re-tool the entire network, but that isn't what I am asking here.  I would like to adapt my existing infrastructure (If possible) instead of re-tooling it.  Is this possible?

Comment: Nobody said anything about "throw away the Windows servers and re-tool the entire network"?

Comment: Ok.  My misunderstanding.  I did not mean to sound challenging.  I am genuinely grateful for answers.  So.. you think I should just run IPv6 DHCP from PFSense....What would happen to my existing Windows IPv6 AD integration?

Comment: That's a good question. AFAIK nothing happens and you just get IPv6 addresses from the pfSense instead of the DC. But I don't have a Windows lab up right now to test it. Nor am I one of the Windows experts around here...